# calculate :$2000 \choose 2000$+....+$2000 \choose 8 $+$2000 \choose 5$+$2000 \choose 2$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients

my attempt:

let's put $2000 \choose 2000$+...+$2000 \choose 1001 $+...+$2000 \choose 8 $+$2000 \choose 5$+$2000 \choose 2$=$A+B$

with $A$=$2000 \choose 2000$+...+$2000 \choose 1001 $

and

$B$=$2000 \choose 998 $...+$2000 \choose 8 $+$2000 \choose 5$+$2000 \choose 2$

using this $ {n \choose k}= {n \choose n-k}$ we can make $A$=$2000 \choose 0$+$2000 \choose 3$+$2000 \choose 6$...+$2000 \choose 999$,and we have $B$=$2000 \choose 998 $...+$2000 \choose 8 $+$2000 \choose 5$+$2000 \choose 2$

so $A+B$=$2000 \choose 0$+$2000 \choose 2$+$2000 \choose 3$+$2000 \choose 5$+...+$2000 \choose 999$=$\sum_{k=0}^{2000} { 2000 \choose k}-\sum_{k=0}^{2000} { 2000 \choose 3k+1}=2^{2000}-\frac{2^{2000}+2}{3}=2.\frac{2^{2000}-1}{3}$

beacause $\sum_{k=0}^{2000} { 2000 \choose 3k+1}=\frac{2^{2000}+2}{3}$.

**does my attempt is correct?**

Comment: How did you find out $\binom{2000}{3k+1}$?

Comment: What is the pattern? Start with $2$ and add $3$ for each term?

Comment: – 
insipidintegrator
  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1352413/1069990

Comment: the pattern is $3k+2$

Comment: You have algebraic errors.  For instance, you have this $A+B=\binom{2000}{0}+\binom{2000}{2}+\binom{2000}{3}+\dots+\binom{2000}{999}$ and try to say that this is equal to a summation $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\color{red}{2000}}\binom{2000}{k}-\dots$  Your sum stopped at 999, not went all the way to 2000.  Your final answer was essentially "taking every third entry of the sum $\binom{2000}{0}+\binom{2000}{1}+\binom{2000}{2}+\dots+\binom{2000}{2000}$ gives us just under two thirds the total of the sum" which of course sounds wrong.  If we were to have guessed, we'd have guessed it be only one third

Comment: You got the correct answer, which is $$[1, 0, 0]\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{2000} = [\dots, \dots, \frac 13 (2^{2000} - 1)]$$  This is question is equivalent to asking "how many subsets of $\dots 2000$ have size $3k+2$".

Comment: @DanielV the OP has a multiplication of two there if you didn't notice.  You say "*you got the correct answer*" and then cite an answer which is different than the OP's.

Comment: DnieLV no it is not the same answer , iknow iam wrong but what i dont know is where is my mistake

Comment: @JMoravitz  yeah now i understanf what you say, but can you edit my answer to be correct?

Comment: An explanation of what I said?  What needs explanation?  Do you recognize that $1+2+3+4+5+6$ is different than $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12$?  The first sum ended much earlier than the other sum.  Do you recognize that $\binom{2000}{0}+\binom{2000}{2}+\binom{2000}{3}+\dots+\binom{2000}{999}$ ends much sooner than $\binom{2000}{0}+\binom{2000}{2}+\binom{2000}{3}+\dots+\binom{2000}{999}\color{red}{+\binom{2000}{1000}+\binom{2000}{1002}+\dots+\binom{2000}{2000}}$?  This has all of these red numbers as well

Comment: yeah i said you are right

Comment: As for how to fix... recognize that$\binom{2000}{2}+\binom{2000}{5}+\dots+\binom{2000}{2000}$ is by using $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ just $\binom{2000}{1998}+\binom{2000}{1995}+\dots+\binom{2000}{3}+\binom{2000}{0}$, so if we called $X$ the original sum we have $2X$ is equal to the sum of everything but the $3k+1$ terms.  Continue like you were trying to do, this time being allowed to use the same limits on the summation correctly, and get the value of $2X$ at the end, completing the problem to get the value of $X$ by dividing that result by two.

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right, I missed "2."

Answer (score 1):

$$S={2000 \choose 2} + {2000 \choose 5} + {2000 \choose 8} + {2000 \choose 11} + \cdots + {2000 \choose 2000}$$

Consider the function $f(x)=x(1+x)^{2000}$. Applying roots of unity filter,

$$S=\frac{2^{2000}+\omega(1+w)^{2000}+\omega^2(1+w^2)^{2000}}3=\frac{2^{2000}+\omega^2+\omega}3=\frac{2^{2000}-1}3$$

Note that a factor of $x$ has been multiplied with our function in question to account for the offset of the starting point.

Comment: PS: Other users have pointed out the errors in OP's solution. My answer is purely for the sake of providing a simple solution to the question, which may be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C=\sum_{k=0}^{666}{2000 \choose 3k+2}$, using symmetry of binomial coefficients $C=\sum_{k=0}^{666}{2000 \choose 3k}$. Let $B=\sum_{k=0}^{666}{2000 \choose 3k+1}$.

$$2^{2000}=\sum_{n=0}^{2000}{2000 \choose n}=\\\sum_{k=0}^{666}{2000 \choose 3k}+\sum_{k=0}^{666}{2000 \choose 3k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{666}{2000 \choose 3k+2}=2C+B.$$

$$\left(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^{2000}=\left(1+\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\right)^{2000}=
\sum_{n=0}^{2000}{2000 \choose n}\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^n.$$

$$\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^3=1\Rightarrow\\
\sum_{n=0}^{2000}{2000 \choose n}\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^n=C+B\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)+C\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^2=\\
B\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)+C\left(\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)=(B-C)\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right).$$

$$\left(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^{6}=1\Rightarrow \left(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^{2000}=\left(\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)^{2}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}2i.$$

$$(B-C)\left(-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}2i \Rightarrow B-C=1 \Rightarrow B=C+1.$$

$$2^{2000}=2C+B=3C+1 \Rightarrow C=\frac{2^{2000}-1}3.$$

Answer (score 0):

> $${2000 \choose 0} + {2000 \choose 2} + {2000 \choose 3} + {2000 \choose 5} + \cdots + {2000 \choose 999}$$ $$ = \sum_{k=0}^{2000} {2000 \choose k} - \sum_{0 \le k <= 2000 \\ k\equiv 1 \pmod 3} {2000 \choose k}$$

This step is wrong.